# Open Bluetooth settings programmatically from UIAlertController

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth

As titled, the question is how can I open bluetooth settings programmatically from my App? 
I checked all answers on stackoverflow and not even one is working fine with iOS 11. All of them are old answers for is below 11 or are left without answer. All I can make is take me to general settings or app settings, but I want user to be taken directly to Bluetooth settings, so he can turn it on.

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Bluetooth is off", message: "Please turn on your bluetooth", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Go to settings", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { (action) in
                switch action.style {
                case .default:
                    let url = URL(string: "App-Prefs:root=Bluetooth") //for bluetooth setting
                    let app = UIApplication.shared
                    app.openURL(url!)
                    print("default")
                case .cancel:
                    print("cancel")
                case .destructive:
                    print("destrucive")
                }
```

What I tried more, also without result:

```
UIApplication.shared.openURL(NSURL(string: "prefs:root=General&path=Bluetoth")! as URL)
```

Or:

```
let url = URL(string: "App-Prefs:root=Bluetooth")
```

All above is not working

Comment: iOS has never publicly supported any URL scheme to launching any Settings page except your own app's page.

Comment: so is there any way to add bluetooth switch on my app's setting page?

Comment: No. There is no way.

Comment: That's seriously poor for iOS... Anyway, thanks

Comment: OK, im changing it. Thanks

Comment: Apple will reject your app and potentially kick you off the store for using either "prefs:root=bluetooth" or "app-prefs:root=bluetooth". Sadly there is no alternative I can find. UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString is a lousy substitute that takes user to your app's custom settings and will likely confuse users that need to go to Settings > Bluetooth to connect to your device

Comment: For me the `let url = URL(string: "App-Prefs:root=Bluetooth")` works with iOS15 and Swift 5. @EdoftheMountain where did you find that using this line could potentially reject your app from the store?

Comment: @MattiaDucci - were you able to confirm that using `App-Prefs:root..` will cause rejection of the app ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

So after some deep research (I couldn't believe that it is not possible) and tries with fails I can write a short answer (summary) for my question. As @maddy wrote, iOS doesn't support URL scheme to launching any direct settings, only to General Settings (the list of all settings), or to Application Settings (your application settings (which you can implement)/permissions list). Unfortunately, for you application settings you can't add there also any of iOS System settings to be easy accessed there. Poor..

To go to General Settings you can use:

```
let url = URL(string: "App-Prefs:root=General")
```

To go to YouApp Settings your can use:

```
let url = URL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)
```

And of course remember to open that URL: (Yes, I know you can do it all in one line)

```
let app = UIApplication.shared
app.openURL(url!)
```

Also, as @Paulw11 mentioned, you can open bluetooth settings directly by CBCentralManagerShowPowerAlertKey option. So when you open your app and instantiate CBCentralManager the built-in alert dialog will popup, telling you that you need to "turn on bluetooth to use accessories (peripherals) with your app", with 2 buttons: Settings (that direct's you to bluetooth settings) and OK (dismiss dialog). Unfortunately this shows up when instantiating central manager, so if you want to hold central manager for your whole app (like singleton etc) than it's not so good as you want, cause it will popup only once. In other case that might be it..

NOW! There is something really wrong with ios bluetooth. In iOS you can turn on/off your bluetooth by 2 ways: one from Settings -> Bluetooth, and the second one by swiping from down to top and selecting bluetooth icon. BUT. Now, when you do it by second way, the bluetooth in Settings is still turned on! So even if you open your application and the bluetooth Alert Dialog will popup, and you select go to settings, you will see that bluetooth is ON.

That is really strange here on iOS..

So, in short summary, the answer for my question is:

YOU CANNOT OPEN BLUETOOTH SETTINGS PROGRAMATICALLY by your own AlertDialog. You can use built-in iOS CBCentralManager AlertDialog.

Hope I saved some of your time.

**opening URL For iOS 10+** (when I changed version in my project I had to change it):

```
app.open(url!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
```

**Bluetooth strange behavior - update**

As I mentioned above, you can switch bluetooth on/off by two ways, which causes strange behavior. Now I should make myself better at this point: that was strange behavior for me (I was used to Android before). Now I know why this behavior is like this. It is because, the way of turning bluetooth by the second way I described (swiping top from down and pressing bluetooth icon) TURNS OFF NOT BLUETOOTH CONNECTION, BUT IT TURNS OFF ALLOWING CONNECTIONS (bluetooth is still turned on, but can not connect with devices (which in apps is treated as bluetooth would be turned off!!). But still you can not manage it programatically anyway.. And I still think that it should be improved by apple.

**Warning**

As @user3620372 wrote, using prefs urls can cause app rejection with:

> Your app uses the "prefs:root=" non-public URL scheme, which is a
>   private entity. The use of non-public APIs is not permitted on the App
>   Store because it can lead to a poor user experience should these APIs
>   change.

Comment: Just a little warning, it can cause some rejection. I just had an app rejected ("Your app uses the "prefs:root=" non-public URL scheme, which is a private entity. The use of non-public APIs is not permitted on the App Store because it can lead to a poor user experience should these APIs change.").

Comment: if they want it, they got it... im instantiating the class each time i verify the bluetooth is off :P

Comment: @user3620372 you are totally right :) I'll edit my answer for that

Comment: Apple will reject your app and potentially kick you off the store for using either "prefs:root=bluetooth" or "app-prefs:root=bluetooth". Sadly there is no alternative I can find. UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString is a lousy substitute that takes user to your app's custom settings and will likely confuse users that need to go to Settings > Bluetooth to connect to your device.

Comment: Seems like iOS 12 turn off BT from control center, only disable new connections.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot open the preferences directly, but if you include [`CBCentralManagerShowPowerAlertKey`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbcentralmanageroptionshowpoweralertkey) with a value of `true` when you create your `CBCentralManager` then iOS will prompt the user to turn Bluetooth on if it is turned off. The alert shown by iOS includes a button to open the Bluetooth settings.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I knew about it, but that was not what I was looking for :)

Comment: Problem is that if the user "turns off" Bluetooth from Control Center, the system alert does not show. I would have used this, but the inconsistency is a deal breaker.

Comment: That is because if Bluetooth is turned off from control center, it isn't actually off. Regardless, it doesn't change the answer. There is no way you can open Bluetooth preferences directly and have your app accepted by Apple.

Comment: You are offering the system alert as a solution for getting the user directly to Bluetooth settings and I am letting others know that it's not a viable solution since it does not display consistently. I have actually opened a bug with Apple on this since CBCentralManager reports a poweredOff state if a user "turns off" Bluetooth from Control Center, the same as if the user turned off Bluetooth in Settings.

Comment: They are using the "Poweredoff" state to indicate "Bluetooth not available to your app".

Answer (score 1):

You can use theses extensions:

```
extension UIApplication {

    static func openAppSettings(completion: @escaping (_ isSuccess: Bool) -> ()) {
        guard let url = URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString) else {
            completion(false)
            return
        }

        let app = UIApplication.shared

        app.open(url) { isSuccess in
            completion(isSuccess)
        }
    }

    static func openPhoneSettings(completion: @escaping (_ isSuccess: Bool) -> ()) {
        guard let url = URL(string: "App-Prefs:root=General") else {
            completion(false)
            return
        }

        let app = UIApplication.shared

        app.open(url) { isSuccess in
            completion(isSuccess)
        }
    }

}
```

And you can use it like this:

```
UIApplication.openPhoneSettings { isSuccess in
      if isSuccess == false {
           //Display error
      }
 }
```

Or:

```
UIApplication.openAppSettings { isSuccess in
      if isSuccess == false {
           //Display error
      }
 }
```

Comment: Using the prefs URL is considered private api and will result in your app being rejected

Comment: Apple will reject your app and potentially kick you off the store for using either "prefs:root=bluetooth" or "app-prefs:root=bluetooth". Sadly there is no alternative I can find. UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString is a lousy substitute that takes user to your app's custom settings and will likely confuse users that need to go to Settings > Bluetooth to connect to your device

Answer (score 1):

```
_ = CBCentralManager(delegate: nil, queue: nil, options: [CBCentralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey:true])
```

The CBCentralManager is the class of CoreBluetooth, which is support by Apple, you can place this code in a method that called by a click action,

then it will pop up an alert view that ask you to choose an option, if u choose setting it will go to bluetooth settings page of iPhone. because u don't use this, so it may release after execute. but must u must turn off the bluetooth setting, or it will not pop up the alert view

```
let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
    button.setTitle("check bluetooth state", for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didClick), for: .touchUpInside)


@objc func didClick(){
     _ = CBCentralManager(delegate: nil, queue: nil, options: [CBCentralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey:true])
}
```

Comment: sorry for that, I had update the answer, if something wrong, thanks for comment